# iText throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on creation of PdfReader

Tags: java, itext

I use the following code to create a PdfReader instance:

```
FileInputStream pdfIn = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/20501217.pdf");
ByteArrayOutputStream stampedPdfBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
```

This throws an exception producing the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:323)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.removeUnusedNode(PdfReader.java:3042)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.removeUnusedObjects(PdfReader.java:3086)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:528)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:247)
```

I'm using iText version 5.0.4, and the PDF is valid.

Comment: can u upload full code ?

Comment: **a)** 5.0.4 is pretty old. Does the error also occur with iText 5.4.x? **b)** Can you supply a sample PDF giving rise to that issue?

Comment: Agreed: I'm the original developer of iText, and the question is unanswerable as long as you don't provide the PDF. Note that I once saw this problem in a PDF that referenced to a negative object: -1 0 R. That's technically impossible. Object numbers can't be negative. Nevertheless, we changed iText so that it can read such broken files. (You say it's valid, but being able to open a file in Adobe Reader doesn't always mean it's valid!)